# Ask "contains all Borel sets" in Riesz Representation theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Borel set is a difficult concept for me to understand. Someone from this website suggests "Do not try to wrap your head around each and every Borel set. It suffices to wrap your head around the concept of the Borel set". For me, I know the definition of Borel set fluently. It is the smallest sigma algebra containing all of the open sets. I also know we can change open to closed in this definition. But the concept is still too abstract for me to understand.

In Riesz Representation theorem, it says there exists a sigma algebra that contains all Borel sets in X (Papa Rudin theorem 2.14). I feel difficult in understanding **all Borel sets**. Borel set is the smallest sigma algebra that contains all open sets. How many Borel sets can we construct? Suppose I already own a Borel set. I think by union, intersection open sets, I can have another Borel sets. But that contradicts contains all open sets. If currently I was told there is one Borel set, then I can understand. But I don't know how I should interpret **all** Borel sets.

Comment: No, a Borel set is a set belonging to the *Borel sigma algebra*: the smallest sigma algebra containing all open sets.

Comment: Then can I say the Borel sigma algebra is the unique one?

Comment: Yes, given a metric space $X$, the Borel sigma algebra is the *smallest* sigma algebra containing all open sets of $X$. The uniqueness follows from "smallest". Any other sigma algebra on $X$ containing all open sets of $X$ must also contain the Borel sigma algebra on $X$.

Comment: Somewhat more concrete is that if $X$ is a metric space, the Borel sigma algebra on $X$ is the smallest sigma algebra that makes every continuous $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ measurable.

Comment: @Mason I know this as the property of Borel sets. Do you mean this is also can be viewed as the definition?

Comment: @Mason Any tutorial notes that I can refer? From my textbook (Papa Rudin), it says if X is a measurable space, then every continuous mapping of X is Borel measurable.

Comment: @Mariana No I don't think this is true for general topological spaces $X$, even if $X$ is LCH. It is true for metric spaces because for any closed $F$, we have $F = f^{-1}(\{0\})$, where $f(x) = d(x, F)$.